# Propel reverse generating tables but no column information in schema.xml

Tags: propel, propel2

I am using Propel 2 with Postgres database. When I run the following command, it appears to work, but in the generated schema.xml file, I do not get any column information:

```
vendor\bin\propel reverse -v --verbose "db"
Reading database structure of database `db` using dsn `pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db`
SchemaParser `Propel\Generator\Reverse\PgsqlSchemaParser` chosen
Successfully reverse engineered 8 tables
Writing XML file to generated-reversed-database\schema.xml
Schema reverse engineering finished.
```

The generated schema.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="db" defaultIdMethod="native" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
  <table name="sometable" idMethod="native" phpName="SomeTable">
    <unique name="sometable_name_key">
      <unique-column name="name"/>
    </unique>
  </table>
  ... other tables, no columns here ...
</database>
```

I am completely stumped on why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.